# Is there an Ethereum trading website which allows overlaying of trade entry and exit points over their chart?

Tags: exchanges, poloniex

I am looking for a website similar to tab-trader app, one which will allow me to use the Poloniex API key and view my buy and sell points overlaid on the current chart?

Tab trader has this functionality, but I would like something which i can access from my computer browser.

Comment: Can't think of any trading website that does this for Ether, but you might want to take a look at [Tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/) where at least you can designate entry/exit points manually, along with a host of other tools.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Coinigy](https://www.coinigy.com/?r=6374be04) It keeps track of your trades with arrows, I like it because it has many trading platform features. You can sign-up with this referral code to help out: [Coinigy website](https://www.coinigy.com/?r=6374be04)

It integrates with many exchanges via API, letting you make all your trades from one place. 5 stars! (I do not work for them or anything, its just my opinion)

[image]

They also host an awesome show about crypto trading that has taught me a lot about trading and how to use the platform : Check out their [Coinigy youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/coinigy)

Hope this helps you.